# Present Perfect/Present Perfect Continuous - which one is better?

Tags: present-perfect

> 1 I'm also lucky in love and I **have gone** out with an amazing girl
> for the last six months.
>
> 2 I'm also lucky in love and I **have been going** out with an amazing
> girl for the last six months.

It seems that both are OK or not? What's the difference?

Comment: The continuous (second) version is more likely (or at least, *safer*). The first one could be understood to imply that you've just broke up with your amazing girlfriend (or perhaps that you're *planning* to dump her very soon! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I've gone out with an amazing girl for the last six months" leaves it open whether or not you're still going out with her and puts a little more emphasis on the fact that you have had the experience of going out with her.

"I've been going out with an amazing girl for the last six months" suggests to the listener that you're at this moment still going out with her. It also puts more emphasis on how that person's presence in your life has consequences for you in the present (maybe it helps explain why you're looking so happy with life these days, for example).

So the best choice between the two options (as so often) depends on what precisely you're trying to express.

In the examples you gave, I suspect the second option is more likely to be the one you want, as it gives the listener the information that you're still together (and closes off the presumably unwelcome possibility that you might have broken up just this morning, and conveys the impression you're absolutely not planning to break it off this evening, for that matter).

Comment: Consider "I've been painting the living room" vs. "I've painted the living room". The first one might be an answer to the question "Why have you got blue spots all over your face and hair?" and the second might be a response to the question "What have you achieved this afternoon?" One puts the emphasis is on the *activity* and the other concentrates on the *result* of that activity. 

With the first option, the painting in the living room might or might not be finished ... but with the second one, the job is definitely done.

Comment: OK. But "I have lived in NY for the last six months"... does it or can it imply that I no longer live there?

Comment: No, it doesn't! But it emphasises what you have achieved or experienced - what you have under your belt, if you like - with less emphasis on what you're doing in your life now. It emphasises *result* rather than *activity*. Though the example is perhaps not the best choice to illustrate the difference between the two tenses ... in this case the difference is not huge. It's certainly not as huge as the difference between, say, "John's been cutting the lawn" and "John's cut the lawn"!

Comment: The difference in your example is one of emphasis, not of actual factual content. Because it doesn't really make much sense to speak of having completed the act of "living in New York" in the same sense as speaking of having finished mowing the lawn or painting the living room.